# implicit conversion fails in function parameter

Tags: c++, parameters, implicit-conversion, function-parameter

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    using std::string;
    using std::distance;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    string s("abc");
    string::const_iterator b = s.begin();
    string::const_iterator e = s.end(); // success
    cout << distance(b, e) << endl;
    cout << distance(b, static_cast<string::const_iterator>(s.end())) << endl;
    cout << distance(b, s.end()) << endl; // error
    return 0;
}
```

End of the string `s.end()` can be [implicitly converted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to `std::string::const_iterator` as `e`, but when it is passed as function parameter, it has to be explicitly casted; otherwise an error is raised in compile time. Why is that?

FYI, `s.begin()` and `s.end()` both seem to return `std::string::iterator`.

> An expression `e` is said to be implicitly convertible to `T2` if and only if `T2` can be copy-initialized from `e`, that is the declaration `T2 t = e;` is well-formed (can be compiled), for some invented temporary `t`.

Comment: Thank you both. Valid answers. My bad not trying non-template methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function has one template parameter

```
template <class InputIterator> 
typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type 
distance(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

So it can not deduce the type of the template parameter because either iterator const or non-const can be used for each function parameter.

You could write without casting the following way

```
std::distance<std::string::const_iterator>(b, s.end())
```

explicitly specifying the template argument.

Another example. This code snippet also will not compile

```
long x = 0;
int y = 0;
std::min(x, y);
```

However if you will write

```
long x = 0;
int y = 0;
std::min<long>(x, y);
```

then the code compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Template function arguments don't get converted. The two arguments to `std::distance` are required to be the same type.